# How to set selected values on multiple select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a multiple select2 input. I am populating all necessary options into it. After that I am sending selected values to it but these selected values are not marked on UI.

I tried below code blocks but not working either of them.

```js
let array = [];

  data.jobDepartments.map(x => {
    array.push(x.id);
  });

  $("#jobDepartment").val(array).trigger("change");
```

```js
let array = [];

  data.jobDepartments.map(x => {
    array.push(x.id);
  });

  $("#jobDepartment").select2("val", array);
```

Here is my settings for select2 input.

```html
<select id="jobDepartment" name="jobDepartment" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-title="jobDepartment"></select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".select2").select2();
});
```

```js
let array = [];

  data.jobDepartments.map(x => {
    array.push(x.id);
  });

  $("#jobDepartment").val(array).trigger("change");
```

Result is: https://prnt.sc/pn0v94

I was expecting this: https://prnt.sc/pn0vvb

Could you help me with it?

Comment: Can you add a snippet?

Comment: I added all snippets. Which snippet you want?

Comment: A snippet is not the code you add, it's the running example of your problem. There's separate option to do that while adding a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praveensov/xtvjf0k7/4/)

Following things are missing in your code:
you should have data config while creating select2

```
$("#e9").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a State",
        allowClear: true,
    templateSelection:function(obj){
    return obj.title;
    },
        data: [{
                'id': 1,
                title: 'test'
            }, {
                'id': 2,
                title: 'test1'
            }
        ]
    });
```

then you have fire your change

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Values do not come selected on select2 multiple.

Comment: I suggest you to create a fiddle in this case. so that everyone in community can help you.. I see some problem in your code.  Id for creating select2 look's not right. Try adding code

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Mistake was coming data. My data id was wrong.